# Why is Safari passing this Modernizr test I wrote for WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, modernizr

I wanted a Modernizr test to check for [`setLocalDescription` with `description` optional](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_rtcpeerconnection_setlocaldescription_description_parameter_optional). Here is what I came up with:

```js
window.Modernizr.addTest('paramlessrtclocaldescription', function () {
    try {
        return window.RTCPeerConnection.prototype.setLocalDescription.length === 0;
    } catch (err) {
        // This can only happen if the browser doesn't support RTCPeerConnection, and
        // we have a separate test for that, but we don't want this test to crash
        // the script.
        return false;
    }
});
```

When I run this test in Firefox 73 (on Windows, from PortableApps.com), it properly returns `false`.

However, when I run it in Safari 14.1, the test returns `true`, even though CanIUse says that Safari does not support this function.

<strike>Furthermore, when I open the JS Console and type `window.RTCPeerConnection.prototype.setLocalDescription.length`, it returns `3` and `window.RTCPeerConnection.prototype.setLocalDescription.length === 0` returns `false`.</strike>

> UPDATE: The above observation is incorrect because manually running the code in the console is being done *after* [`webrtc-adapter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webrtc-adapter) has loaded, and `webrtc-adapter` overrides this function.

Why is Safari passing the Modernizr test even though it is listed as unsupported?

Comment: `window.RTCPeerConnection.prototype.setLocalDescription.length` returns 0 in my Safari 14.1.2 console, FWIW.

Comment: @erip I figured out why that is, and I'm updating the question.

Comment: see also https://github.com/webrtcHacks/adapter/issues/1084 -- not released yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Safari 14.1 ***does*** support this feature, and it seems that it is CanIUse/MDN that is wrong.

It was added to Webkit [in September 2020](https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/266468/webkit).